# How can I get a reference to an element in list using key?

Tags: reactjs

A simple question which I can't find a good answer to.

I have a very large list of items (>1000, possibly greater than 10k). Each of these has a unique key. Is it possible to get a ref to an element by only knowing its key?

I can certainly generate refs myself, but this would require me maintaining a list of refs myself. In general, that is not a big deal, but due to the large list, it would probably be more efficient if there was a method for getting a ref just from the key.

Comment: What do you want to do with the DOM node once you have a reference to it? The `key` prop is used by React internally and is never put on the DOM node, so I don't think you can use that, but you could put it in a data attribute and use that for querying if you really need to: `<div key={someKey} data-key={somKey}> ... </div>`

Comment: First and foremost, I want to change focus to a specific element.

Comment: Alright. Depending on your use case you might get away with something like `document.querySelectorAll(\`[data-key="${someKey}"]\`).focus();`

Comment: Nice. Post an answer and earn your reward. I can verify that this indeed works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key prop is used by React internally and is never put on the DOM node so you can't use that for querying the DOM, but you could put it in a data attribute and use that for querying instead.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    const { key } = event.target.dataset;

    document.querySelectorAll(`input[data-key="${key}"]`)[0].focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <div key={item}>
            <input data-key={item} value={item} />
            <button data-key={item} onClick={this.handleClick}>
              Focus
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```